# Certain amount of variables out of multiple variables with value of more than 0 in python

Tags: python

For example, if I have five variables, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, and v_5, and wanted only 3 of the five variables to have a stored value of more than 0, how would I go about checking this? It doesn't matter which variables have a stored value of more than 0, as long as no more than 3 of these variables do.

If

```
v_1 = 2
v_2 = 3
v_3 = 5
v_4 = 6
v_5 = 0
```

then an error would be returned, because more than 3 of the variables have a value of more than 0, but if

```
v_1 = 2
v_2 = 3
v_3 = 0
v_4 = 6
v_5 = 0
```

then the code would continue or print "no more than 3," because no more than 3 of the variables have a stored value of more than 0.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing something like this, or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: Is it possible to use some data structure like lists?

Comment: using variables where a list would be more logical is a bad idea

Comment: using list we can do this for variables also `if sum(sorted(list([v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5]))[:3]) != sum(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)` raise error